# Mysql if column has certain value then make sure date column is from X date

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can I do a select statement such that `Select * from table`, but only if the column value = 'y' is from a certain date?

So, the date only applies if a column has only a certain value.

How would I go on this?

Comment: you can filter using where

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE datecolumn='2016-12-01'`?

Comment: Downed, your title is catastrophal, formulate it to a round question.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name LIKE '%2016-01-29%'